# How do I make a phone call with nativescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

**I want to make a phone call when I press the button.
I am calling the phone number to the label.
This is my button ;**

```
<ActionBar>
    <NavigationButton (tap)="onBackTap()" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back"></NavigationButton>
    <Label class="action-bar-title" style="font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 10px;" [text]="item.name"></Label>
</ActionBar>

<StackLayout>
<Label class="action-bar-title" style="font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        font-size: 10px;" [text]="item.number"></Label>
    <Button text="&#xff17b; Call!" (tap)="onTap()" class="my-button"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

**this is my onTap() method ;**

```
export class ItemDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    item: IDataItem;

    constructor(
        private _data: DataService,
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _routerExtensions: RouterExtensions
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const id = +this._route.snapshot.params.id;
        this.item = this._data.getItem(id);
    }

    onBackTap(): void {
        this._routerExtensions.back();
    }
    onTap(): void {

    }
}
```

**How do I make a phone call ?**

Comment: @Igor please read the tags before saying duplicate. This is about Nativescript while the link you provided is about web and Android only. Nativescript and Android specific stuffs are totally different.

Comment: @user3502626 - You should be able to see the edit history on questions as well as the comment dates. The question was created on sep. of 2019 at which time I suggested a possible duplicate. 2 months later the tags you are referring to were added by another user. Since then (nov. of 2019) there has been no activity.

Answer (score 3):

You can use plugin [NativeScript Phone](https://github.com/msywensky/nativescript-phone).

Now you have two options:

1. Make a call directly from application - you will need permission `CALL_PHONE`.
2. Open default phone call app with number entered.

In my opinion better is second option because you don't need any additional permissions.

Import TNSPhone:

```
import * as TNSPhone from 'nativescript-phone';
```

And use dial method in your `onTap` method:

```
TNSPhone.dial(123456789, true);
```